# How to obtain TSC (TypeScript Compiler) w/o Node.js

Tags: typescript

Since recently TypeScript compiler is distributed as either source code or Node.js package. Unfortunately, I can't install latest Node.js (I need an older version that could work in Cygwin) and so NPM isn't really an option in my case (I'm also not really enthusiastic about using Node.js overall...). So, is there a way to get TSC alone, without the Node.js package? Perhaps there's some donwloads page on the site w/o a direct link or some such? Maybe some mirror / GitHub fork or something?

TSC source code is written in TypeScript itself, which makes the idea of compiling it, whilst not having a compiler a really futile effort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download it here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790

That's both the typescript compiler and a plugin for VS2012

Comment: Thanks! I figured out that the source code repository already contains a compiled version, so that was another option, just in case.